# Symfony 4 Remove a default set constraint (notBlank) on a RepeatedType Password field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have form builder in a controller

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)

                 ->add('firstname',TextType::class,array(
                     'label' => 'First name',
                     'attr' => array(
                         'class' => 'form-control',
                         'value' => $user->getFirstname()
                     ),
                 ))
                 ->add('surname',TextType::class,array(
                     'label' => 'Last name',
                     'attr' => array(
                         'class' => 'form-control',
                         'value' => $user->getSurname()
                     )
                 ))
                 ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
                     'label' => 'Email',
                     'attr' => array(
                         'class' => 'form-control',
                         'value' => $user->getEmail(),
                     ),
                 ))
                 ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(

                     'type' => PasswordType::class,
                     'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
                     'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 
                        'password-field')),

                     'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
                     'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat 
                      Password'),
                 ))
```

As you can see on the `plainPassword` field there is no constraints set. My intention was to have the user not need to fill this field if they do not want to, however when I submit the form, the `NotBlank` constraint gets triggered and the form doesn't get submitted. I tried setting/adding, `required` to `FALSE`, doesn't work.

I even tried adding a `new Blank()` constraint and still it kept holding to the default constraint.

Is there a way to remove this default `notBlank`constraint ??

Screengrab of the constraint kicking in
[image]

Comment: Check your entity and confirm that you have NotBlank() assert/constraint annotation in plainPassword

Comment: Other approach is set mapped => false in the form. Then, get it in the controller for checking if it has data and set it in that case.

Comment: @AythaNzt , your first comment was the solution. I had noblank() assert annotated for that property. Thanks ever so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AythaNzt's comment. So the Constraint asserted an an annotation on my 'user Entity' class

It was this

```
 /**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 */
private $plainPassword;
```

Removed the `NotBlank()`
So became

```
/**
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 */
private $plainPassword;
```